# How to select rows using outer join

Tags: sql, join, left-join, outer-join

I have two A1 and A2 tables wit single column.

```
A    B
-    -
1    3
2    4
3    5
4    6
```

I need to select records from A which are not in B. For this i tried `select A from [A1] as a  left outer join A2 as c on a.[A]=c.[B]` but it select `1` and `2` more than one time, i want unique results only, `want 1 and 2 only`. Refereed few links [Outer join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-join) but not able to understand fully. I know this is silly question but i am new with joins.

Answer (score 1):

What about `not in` combined with `Distinct` so you're not getting any duplicates

```
select Distinct A
from A1
where A not in (select B from A2)
```

Comment: which will be better join or not in when no of rows is greater than 20k.

Comment: it all depends on your data. You can try comparing the two solutions and pick the one that suits you most. http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join

Answer (score 0):

The SQL request in your question should normally give 1,2,3,4 as results , the following picture shows how different joins work :
[image]

So if you want to display only records that are in A but not in B, it is :

```
SELECT distinct A from A1 a LEFT JOIN B1 b   
ON a.A = b.B  
WHERE b.B is NULL
```

The following [picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448023/what-is-the-difference-between-left-right-outer-and-inner-joins) explains more about different joins and their SQL syntax implementations :
[image]